# Error using Godep on Travis CI automated build for tip version of Go

Tags: go, travis-ci, godeps

I'm using Travis CI to automate builds and tests on my Go project.

The `./Godeps/Godeps.json` looks like this :

```
{
    "ImportPath": "github.com/my_project_path",
    "GoVersion": "go1.5",
    "Packages": [
        "./..."
    ],
    "Deps": [
        {
            "ImportPath": "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus",
            "Comment": "v0.8.7-53-g446d1c1",
            "Rev": "446d1c146faa8ed3f4218f056fcd165f6bcfda81"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `.travis.yml` file looks like this :

```
language: go

go: 
 - 1.3.3
 - 1.4.2
 - 1.5.1
 - release
 - tip

before_install:
 - go get github.com/my_project_path
 - go get github.com/tools/godep

install:
 - godep restore

script:
 - go test -v ./...
```

All other builds work except for `tip` because of `go version`.

The last few lines of the Travis CI log for `tip` are :

```
$ go version

go version devel +e4dcf5c Thu Dec 24 06:55:33 2015 +0000 linux/amd64
go.env

$ go env

GOARCH="amd64"

GOBIN=""

GOEXE=""

GOHOSTARCH="amd64"

GOHOSTOS="linux"

GOOS="linux"

GOPATH="/home/travis/gopath"

GORACE=""

GOROOT="/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go"

GOTOOLDIR="/home/travis/.gimme/versions/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"

GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"

CC="gcc"

GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"

CXX="g++"

CGO_ENABLED="1"
before_install.1

3.52s$ go get github.com/my_project_path
before_install.2

3.34s$ go get github.com/tools/godep

0.02s$ godep restore

godep: Error determing major go version from: "devel"

The command "godep restore" failed and exited with 1 during .

Your build has been stopped.
```

How can I fix this? Am I just stuck with using `go get ./...`?

**EDIT:** It seems someone made a [pull request](https://github.com/tools/godep/pull/387) to fix this.

**EDIT2:** Seems the pull request [was merged](https://github.com/tools/godep/pull/387). Will test if it's fixed soonish.

Comment: I am still getting this issue. Travis does `go get github.com/tools/godep` before running `godep restore` but it fails with "godep: Error comparing go1.4 to devel"

Answer (score 1):

So I asked this question on December 24 2015.

On December 29 2015, github user *zchee* opened a [pull request](https://github.com/tools/godep/pull/387) that fixed the issue mentioned in my question.

On January 4 2016, the pull request was merged into the `master` branch of `godep`. So essentially the issue is now fixed and in order for `Travis CI` to use `godep restore` and test your project against the `tip` version of `Go`, your `.travis.yml` file should look like it does in the question, i.e.:

```
language: go

go: 
 - 1.3.3
 - 1.4.2
 - 1.5.1
 - release
 - tip

before_install:
 - go get github.com/my_project_path
 - go get github.com/tools/godep

install:
 - godep restore

script:
 - go test -v ./...
```